# when change exec-opt native.cgroupdriver to "cgroupfs"，docker can not run correct?

Tags: docker, cgroups

```
my os version : centos7.3
kenerl version : 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
docker version : 1.12.6
```

I modify the config file "/lib/systemd/system/docker.service" ,after change the option "--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver" from systemd to cgroupfs. I find the docker can not run any images!

```
[root@surenode2 system]# cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service |grep cgroup
          --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs \
[root@surenode2 system]# docker images | grep mysql
docker.io/mysql     latest              e799c7f9ae9c        3 weeks ago         407.3 MB
[root@surenode2 system]# docker run -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql
3395c8d505d3fc20d39e25c510a090649f9f447bce985028ea7274e79183d077
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:334: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: \\\"\"\n".
```

And,if I change exec-opt native.cgroupdriver to systemd ,Docker can run any images..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker 1.12.6 ("community edition") is EOL and no longer supported; 
We can install the latest docker version refer to 'https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/'.
When using the latest docker version ,this issue is no longer reproduce !

```
[root@surenode1 ~]# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:1-393732-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 11.8MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 50.86GB
 Metadata Space Used: 581.6kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.147GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.702GiB
Name: surenode1
ID: NIYU:7BRX:JIQP:ZJMW:ZV6N:3336:5JSB:MWVQ:WR72:AO7J:QOEW:CHCA
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

[root@surenode1 ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

[root@surenode1 tmp]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql               latest              e799c7f9ae9c        3 weeks ago         407MB
[root@surenode1 tmp]# ps -ef | grep docker
root     10173     1  1 17:31 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/dockerd **--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs**
root     10177 10173  0 17:31 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
root     10535  9634  0 17:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
[root@surenode1 tmp]# docker run -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql
8f2d30ea779b872604bdf0d3d500de16e17d1409cdc5b2688893202bfcebbf16
[root@surenode1 tmp]#
```

Also,We can find a bug description about this issue. 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1444662